# How to make this javascript run in both IE7 and chrome

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a legacy application that uses frames and this one line is confounding me: `myName = document.anchors("mySettings").innerText;` It works fine in IE7 but in Chrome it says: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Property 'anchors' of object # is not a function**

Turns out the only thing that needs to be done to make it work in Chrome is to replace the round brackets () with square ones []. Problem is, now it won't work in Internet Explorer. IE says: **'document.anchor.mySettings.innerText' is null or not an object**.

Ok, so I tried checking if `document.anchors` is a function like so: `if (typeof document.anchors === "function") {` and if it is, use the round brackets (so it works in IE), else use square brackets (for Chrome). Didn't work. It still goes into the else block for both, so apparently it's not a function in IE either.

So I then tried checking if `document.anchors("mySettings").innerText` and `document.anchors["mySettings"].innerText` was null or not an object like so:    `if (document.anchors["mySettings"].innerText !== null || document.anchors["mySettings"].innerText !== "object") {` in order to address that IE error. Still didn't work.

Is there something wrong with this code? Or is there any easier way that I've overlooked?
Basically all I need is something like:

```
if IE {
    myName = document.anchors("mySettings").innerText;
} else (if chrome) {
    myName = document.anchors["mySettings"].innerText;
}
```

Comment: What is `"mySettings"`? The `id` of the anchor? The `name` of the anchor? There's probably a better cross-browser method to getting a specific element

Comment: I would consider looking into JQuery. It abstract a lot of the browsers differences and offers a unified API

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.anchors, it looks like `document.anchors` is an array. It seems to make more sense to loop over it and check for the element you want. Even better, I'd use `document.getElementsByTagName("a")` and then loop over those and find the one you want

Comment: @Ian: Like `document.forms`, `document.images`, and `document.all`, it’s a magic array. Try it on this page: `document.anchors['top-bar']`

Comment: It's unclear in your question: sometime you use `document.anchor` others `document.anchors`. Is that just typo ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue sorry yes just a typo. Fixed

Comment: @Ian good question. It looks like it's the name of a table cell in the footer section of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting a browser is always wrong! Instead, try one feature, then try the other. In this case, checking the property (Chrome) is a little easier to work:

```
var anchor = document.anchors.mySettings;

if (!anchor) {
    anchor = document.anchors("mySettings");
}

myName = anchor.innerText;
```

Also, have you tried this in Firefox? Opera? Safari? Make sure to! There are not only two browsers in the world.

Frankly, you shouldn’t be using named anchors anyways; give them `id`s, access them consistently using `document.getElementById`, and keep the same hash behaviour.

```
<a href="http://example.com/" name="mySettings" id="my-settings">
```

```
var myName = document.getElementById('my-settings').innerText;
```

Note also that `textContent` is the standard property for an element’s text content; for IE7 support, I’d still use `firstChild.nodeValue`.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, it is. Unless it’s for analytics, and doing that in JavaScript is still wrong. Prove otherwise?

Comment: @Tom, not **always** wrong (always is such a strong word). But often a bad approach. I think the point false is trying to make is that you should detect features, not specific browsers.

Comment: It only needs to work in Chrome and IE since those are the only two officially supported browsers at this company.

Comment: Ok didn't understand the first chunk of code you wrote but that last part about using document.getElementById worked like a charm! All that was needed was that one line and now it works! :)

Comment: @false would you mind if I deleted the first part of your response for clarity's sake, so it's easier for people reading to tell what the correct answer was?

Comment: @user1985189: Well, they’re both correct and important…